# Generate m random numbers out of a given array of n numbers

Tags: algorithm

I have one doubt. Does creating random set m integers out of n array elements means that all the m elements have to be unique, because the probability of selecting each number is equal.

For example, If I have original array as {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} (n = 10) and I am selecting 5 elements(m = 5) randomly. So does that mean that {1, 1, 5, 7, 9} is an unacceptable solution because 1 has occurred twice.

Comment: The term "set" generally implies, unique elements, yes.

Comment: If you pick a random element from a set, in theory each option will have an equal change. In reality though, it depends on the random generator, as many favour smaller numbers.

Comment: You need to say "with replacement" or "without replacement" to make it clear if it's not already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really are selecting randomly from an array, then each selection might be the same element, so a procedure that tried to build a set of m elements from an array of n elements (where n>=m) might never terminate. For example, it might just pick the same element over and over, thus never increasing the size of the set of selected elements.

Comment: I am using the random number generator that is present in Math class in Java. `int rand(int lower, int higher){
  return lower + (int)(Math.random() * (higher - lower + 1));
 }`

Comment: In this piece of code (higher - lower) is the range within which I need to gererate the number. So I guess I cannot do much about the random() in Java Math class

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on the use case. The normal way to get random numbers is by using [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm. So basically you pick a number and then move that number to the end of the array and reduce the size of the array by 1 so that the next number you choose doesn't repeat.

Basic pseudo code:

```
  for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

A short answer to your question is NO. Selecting means choosing an element ( not copying/replicating) from a given set and by doing so we are not allowed to change the original set. m elements don't have to be unique but the original element set ( Space ) should remain unchanged.